# Problema al querer modificar un registro de la base de datos me trae uno erroneo

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy practicando php y me salta este error al querer modificar un registro de la base de datos, dejo fotos y codigo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

funcion que me muestra la tabla

```
function MostrarTablaProductoABM($filas)
{

    $s  = "";
    $s .= "<table border=\"1\" class=\"\">";

    foreach($filas as $fila)
    {
        $s .= "<tr>";   

        $s .= "<td>" . $fila["nombre"] . "</td>";
         $s .= "<td>" . $fila["precio"] . "</td>";
         $s .= "<td>" . $fila["stock"] . "</td>";

        $s .= "<td>";

        $destino = "ProductoModificar.php?op=b&id=". $fila["id"];
        //$destino = "#"
        $s .= "<a href=\"" . $destino . "\">Modificar</a>"; 
        $s .= "</td>";

        $s .= "<td>";
        $destino = "ProductoEliminar.php?op=b&id=" . $fila["id"];
        //$destino = "#";
        $s .= "<a href=\"" . $destino . "\">Eliminar</a>"; 
        $s .= "</td>";

        $s .= "</tr>";  

    }

    $s .= "</table>";


    $s .= "<br/>";

    $s .= "<a href=\"ProductoCTRL.php?op=a\">Nuevo</a>";

    return $s;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?php


if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

require_once("fnc/funciones.php");



print_r($_SESSION);

// Limpiar Inputs
LimpiarInput($_POST);


// Verificar errores
$errores = array();


//----------------------------------------
if ( !isset($_SESSION["txtProducto"]) )
{
    $errores[] = "Producto no esta definido";   
}
else
{
    $producto = trim($_SESSION["txtProducto"]); 

    if ( empty($producto) )
    {
        $errores[] = "Producto esta vacio";
    }


    if ( !is_string($producto) )
    {
        $errores[] = "Producto no es una cadena";   
    }
}
//----------------------------------------
if ( !isset($_SESSION["txtPrecio"]) )
{
    $errores[] = "Precio no esta definido"; 
}
else
{
    $precio = trim($_SESSION["txtPrecio"]); 

    if ( empty($precio) )
    {
        $errores[] = "Precio esta vacio";
    }


    if ( !is_numeric($precio) )
    {
        $errores[] = "Precio no es un numero";  
    }
}
//----------------------------------------
if ( !isset($_SESSION["txtStock"]) )
{
    $errores[] = "Stock no esta definido";  
}
else
{
    $stock = trim($_SESSION["txtStock"]);   

    if ( empty($_SESSION) )
    {
        $errores[] = "Stock esta vacio";
    }


    if ( !is_numeric($stock) )
    {
        $errores[] = "Stock no es un numero";   
    }
}   
//----------------------------------------

if ( !empty($errores) )
{
    $s  = "";

    $s .= "<h4>Errores</h4>";

    foreach ($errores as $error)
    {
        $s .= "<h4>$error</h4>";
    }
}
?>
```

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo01.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">

        <?php

            if ( empty($errores) ) 

                                        $ok = EliminarProductoPorId($_SESSION["idProducto"]);

                                        if ( $ok )
                                        {
                                            echo "<h3>El Producto se elimino exitosamente</h3>";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo "<h3>Error al eliminar el Producto</h3>";
                                        }















        ?> 

        <br/>
        <a href="Modificar-AgregarProducto.php">Volver</a>



    </div>
</body>
```

```
print_r($_SESSION);
require_once("fnc/funciones.php");

$tituloHTML = "";


    $tituloHTML = "Eliminar Producto";
                        $tituloSubmit = "Eliminar";
                        $disabled = "disabled = \"disabled\"";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $tituloHTML;?></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo01.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">

<?php include("enlaceLogout.php"); ?>

<h2> <?php echo $tituloHTML; ?> </h2>   

<form action="ProductoDestinoEliminar.php" method="POST">




    <p>
    Producto
    <input  type="text" name="txtProducto" id="txtProducto" <?php echo $disabled; ?>  value="<?php echo $_SESSION["txtProducto"]; ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
    Precio
    <input  type="text" name="txtPrecio" id="txtPrecio" <?php echo $disabled; ?>  value="<?php echo $_SESSION["txtPrecio"]; ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
    Stock
    <input  type="text" name="txtStock" id="txtStock" <?php echo $disabled; ?>  value="<?php echo $_SESSION["txtStock"]; ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
    <input  type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="<?php echo $tituloSubmit;?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
    <a href="Producto.php">Cancelar</a>
    </p>
    </form>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Por favor, la foto del php, podrías añadirla como texto? será más fácil para aquel que quiera hacer pruebas con lo que proporcionas. Gracias

Comment: ahora creo que quedo mas claro puede ser?, me falto agregar que me mostraba y su codigo

Comment: aja y cuales el error que envia?? o debemos adivinarlo??

Comment: ya perdon xD, cuando selecciono un producto y le doy borrar/modificar me trae un producto que habia borrado anterior mente y no se porque , si te fijas en la primera foto y y miras los productos veras que ninguno coincide con el de la 2° foto